# Destructor of a template called at the end of constructor of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, destructor

I have some trouble with a template class I am working on. Here is the definition of my classes (I kept only the essential parts, where the error comes from):
`Sampler.h`

```
#ifndef SAMPLER_H
#define SAMPLER_H

#include "matrix.h"
#include "MatrixOperations.h"

template <class T>
class Sampler
{
      public:
             virtual T getnumber()=0;
};

const Matrix ZEROS = zeros_mat(1,1);
const Matrix UNIT = unit_mat(1);

class NormalSampler_multi:public Sampler<Matrix>
{
   public:
           virtual Matrix getnumber();
           NormalSampler_multi(Matrix m=ZEROS, Matrix VarCovar=UNIT);
           void printMean();
           void printVar();
   private:
            Matrix mu;
            Matrix var;


};
#endif
```

And the cpp file:
`Sampler.cpp`

```
#include "Sampler.h"
#include"matrix.h"
#include "MatrixOperations.h"

#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

NormalSampler_multi::NormalSampler_multi(Matrix m, Matrix VarCovar){
    if(m.get_nbColumns()>1 && m.get_nbRows()>1){
        cout << "The mean should be a 1d-matrix\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(VarCovar.isSymmetric()==false){
        cout << "The Variance-Covariance matrix should be symmetric\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    mu = m;
    var = VarCovar;
}

void NormalSampler_multi::printMean(){mu.print_matrix();}
void NormalSampler_multi::printVar(){var.print_matrix();}


Matrix NormalSampler_multi::getnumber(){//Not implemented yet};
```

Here is my problem. When I run the following code:
`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

#include "matrix.h"
#include "MatrixOperations.h"
#include "Sampler.h"

int main(){

    //Vector of means
    Matrix mean(5,1);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        mean(i,0) = i;
    }

    //Creation of the multidimensional sampler
    NormalSampler_multi Z(mean, variance);
    cout << "Print of the mean after assignment:" << endl;
    Z.printMean();
    cout << "Print of the variance after assignment" << endl;
    Z.printVar();
    return 0;

}
```

The values of `mu` and `var` are not the same as the values of `mean` and `variance` (as they should be). When I looked into it, I found out that the destructor of the `Matrix` class is called at the end of the constructor of `NormalSampler_multi`. So I guess it deletes the values of `mu` and `sigma`, but I really don't understand why and how to solve it.

The (essential part of the) Matrix class is defined below:
`Matrix.h`

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H


class Matrix{
public:
    Matrix(int nbRows=0, int nbColumns=0); 
    Matrix(const Matrix& a); 
    ~Matrix(); 

    //Access to elements
    double& operator()(int i, int j);  

    int get_nbRows(void) const;
    int get_nbColumns(void) const;

    //Useful functions
    void print_matrix(void);

protected:
    int n; //Number of rows
    int p; //Number of columns
    double **pt; //Pointer to elements

};

#endif // MATRIX_H
```

and their implementation:
`Matrix.cpp`

```
#include "matrix.h"
#include "MatrixOperations.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

Matrix::Matrix(int nbRows, int nbColumns){
    n = nbRows;
    p = nbColumns;
    pt = new double*[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        pt[i] = new double[p];}
    //Initialize the array to 0
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<p; j++){
            pt[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& a){
    n = a.n;
    p = a.p;
    pt = new double*[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        pt[i] = new double[p];
        for(int j=0; j<p; j++){
            pt[i][j] = a.pt[i][j];
        }
    }

}

Matrix::~Matrix(){
    cout << "destructor called\n";
    delete[] pt;}

int Matrix::get_nbRows(void) const {return n;}
int Matrix::get_nbColumns(void) const {return p;}


double &Matrix::operator()(int i, int j){
    if ((i < 0)||(i>=n)||(j < 0)||(j>=p))
    {
        cout << "Index out of bounds! \n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return pt[i][j];
}

//Print a matrix on the console
void Matrix::print_matrix(void){
    cout << "[";
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            cout << "[";
        for(int j=0; j<p; j++){
            cout << (*this)(i,j);
            if(j<p-1){cout  << ",";}
        }
        cout << "]";
        if(i<n-1){cout << ",\n";}
        else{}
    }
    cout << "]\n";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `NormalSampler_multi(Matrix m=ZEROS, Matrix VarCovar=UNIT);`  - the parameters `m` and `VarCovar` will be destroyed when the constructor ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NormalSampler_multi(Matrix m, Matrix VarCovar) {`  - the parameters `m` and `VarCovar` will be destroyed when the constructor ends.

Your problems may be due to `Matrix` not obeying the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).  The default-generated assignment operator invoked by `mu = m; var = VarCovar;` does a memberwise assignment and this messes up your class invariants.  You end up with `mu.pt == m.pt`, and then when `m` is destroyed, `mu.pt` is a dangling pointer.

An easy solution to this is to replace `pt` with `vector<vector<double>>` and then your class will fit the rule of zero.  Alternatively you could implement a correct assignment operator.

(Footnote - there might be other issues, this was just one that stood out).

Comment: thanks! I didn't know the rule of 3/5/0 tbh. I will try to implement a correct assignment operator to fix it.

Comment: Just to let you know implementing the assignment operator works perfectly fine. Thanks again!